# How do you create a table in Cassandra using phantom for Scala?

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

I am trying to run the example on https://github.com/websudos/phantom/blob/develop/phantom-example/src/main/scala/com/websudos/phantom/example/basics/SimpleRecipes.scala
,So I created a Recipe and tried to insert it using `insertNewRecord(myRecipe)` and got the following exception: `....InvalidQueryException: unconfigured columnfamily my_custom_table`.
I checked using cqlsh and the keyspace was created but the table was not.

So my question is, how do I create the table using phantom?
This is never mentioned in any of the example code and I also could not figure it out by going over the phantom source code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create the table using schema autogeneration. Simply execute:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import com.websudos.phantom.dsl._


// To execute this, you need an implicit keySpace and a session.
Await.ready(SimpleRecipes.create.ifNotExists().future(), 3.seconds)
```

Comment: how do I get the session and keySpace?

Comment: https://github.com/websudos/phantom/blob/develop/phantom-dsl/src/test/scala/com/websudos/phantom/db/TestDatabase.scala#L40