# How to create keyspace and insert data using Phantom dsl

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

I'm using this library for the first time, and I ran into a problem. I did everything according to the documentation, but nothing is working, and i don't know why. Here is my table model:

```
trait CassandraModel

object CassandraModel {

  case class TaskData(notifyid: String,
                      notifyType: String)
      extends CassandraModel

  abstract class TaskDataCassandra extends Table[TaskDataCassandra, TaskData] {
    object notifyid       extends StringColumn with PartitionKey
    object notifyType     extends StringColumn


    def store(record: TaskData): InsertQuery.Default[TaskDataCassandra, TaskData] =
      insert
        .value(_.notifyId, record.notifyId)
        .value(_.notifyType, record.notifyType)
  }
}
```

And DataBase with DatabaseProvider:

```
class AppDatabase(override val connector: CassandraConnection) extends Database[AppDatabase](connector) {
  object taskDataCassandra extends TaskDataCassandra with Connector
}

trait AppDatabaseProvider extends DatabaseProvider[AppDatabase]
```

So, when i starting my app, i'm trying to create a keyspace, but nothing is happens

```
object Boot extends App with AmqpConnector with ServiceRestRoute with JsonSerializer with AppDatabaseProvider {

  override def database: AppDatabase = new AppDatabase(CassandraConnector.createCassandraConnection)

  database.taskDataCassandra.create.ifNotExists()

}
```

store method also doesn't works

Comment: You need `.future()` and wait until it completed. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31124834/how-do-you-create-a-table-in-cassandra-using-phantom-for-scala

Answer (score 1):

Read through the documentation properly and the differences will be obvious. The thing to read is the [**Database Docs**](https://github.com/outworkers/phantom/blob/develop/docs/basics/database.md).

You have 2 options. You can call `database.create()`, which is a blocking creation operation that will create all the tables inside the database.

Option 2 is to call `database.taskDataCassandra.create.ifNotExists().future()`.

If you do not use `future()`, all you have is a query generated, you are not actually executing anything. If you check the return type of `database.taskDataCassandra.create.ifNotExists()` it will be a `CreateQuery`, wheres if you add `future()` you get a `Future[Result]`.

Hope this makes sense.